# How to fetch whatsApp profile picture android

Tags: android

How to get whatsapp profile pictures in android using android studio programatically

```
id = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
String name = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String number = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```